# Add Custom Field in customer registration frontend side form

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

**I want to add country-state functionality to the customer registration form and how to save it**

[image]

Comment: There already is the country and the state (according to the selected country) on the customer address. Are you sure you need to duplicate this fields on the customer entity ?

Comment: yes, but in frontend side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your customer_account_create.xml file. This Will add all Address Fields in Registration Form in frontend only

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_address_fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: then how to get this value as a customer attribute for add field in customer account information in admin side?

Comment: I want to add functionality for a country region in the customer account information section

Comment: You can't access this value as a customer attribute. You have to access these values as simply Magento did for accessing address values.

Comment: how to change the sort order of address field

Comment: using XML file without overriding phtml file is possible?